# Yum as eth->wlan adaptor

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, ethernet

Is there a way to make a yun an Ethernet-wifi bridge? Applications include giving wifi to raspberry pi and other Ethernet only devices and vice versa.

Comment: You know you can get a real high-performance Wifi access point for much cheaper...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Already got one of those...in the other room. And no, I can't move it or the wired only device.

Comment: I'm sure any shop will be happy to sell you another one. Or three! Probably should've said "Wifi client" since some devices only support AP mode. And for an RPi, just get a USB Wifi adapter...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I don't have a lot of money. Besides, i have a spare yun (haven't found something to do with it yet besides hosting a kittens game server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  I use one to connect my Sky box (Ethernet only) to my WiFi network,

It's not an easy task though and you have to have a good understanding of networking and routing.

Basically you have to set the Yun up as a router to route packets between the Ethernet and the WiFi interfaces.  You set the Ethernet interface up on a separate subnet to your existing WiFi network, and set a static route on your main router to send traffic destined to your new Ethernet subnet to the Yun's WiFi IP address.

Your Ethernet devices can then be allocated an IP address on the Ethernet subnet (turn on DCHP for that interface on the Yun) and will use the Yun as the default gateway.

There are probably ways you can enable bridging on the Yun to tie the Ethernet and WiFi interfaces together so it becomes transparent but I haven't investigated that yet.